# how to swap values by index in Golang

Tags: go, swap, assign

In python's `numpy`, one can swap values by index within a list easily like this:

```
a[[2, 3, 5]] = a[[5, 2, 3]]
```

Is there a good way to implement this function in Golang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go doesn't have fancy indexing like that; the closest you can do is

```
a[2],a[3],a[5] = a[5],a[2],a[3]
```

using regular indexing and regular [tuple assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments).

Comment: What if I have a variable length indexes to be swapped. Can I implement it in place? The current method I can figure out is to make a copy of them and assign them back to the original list...

Comment: @luoshao23 yeah, you can't do that without a temporary. Go won't implicitly allocate arbitrary amounts of memory :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a *good* way to implement this function in Go[...][? emph mine]

No. Go doesn't provide syntax for this.
Note that *inplace* permutation is a hard problem (and probably numpy doesn't do this under the hood either).

Copy and permute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to that you can over engineer some solution, but will create a lot of problem and handling

To give you an idea about what I mean see this [Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/WTrmBgNeEsC)
Go passes Slices as reference so making a function to swap in place and you get something like this

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    err := swap(a, "1,3,5=>0,2,4")
    fmt.Println(a, err)
}

func swap(arr []int, str string) error {
    parts := strings.Split(str, "=>")
    if len(parts) != 2 {
        return errors.New("Invalid Input")
    }

    leftIndices := strings.Split(parts[0], ",")
    rightIndices := strings.Split(parts[1], ",")

    if len(leftIndices) != len(rightIndices) {
        return errors.New("Swap Indices not Balanced")
    }
    
    fmt.Println(leftIndices, rightIndices)

    for i := 0; i < len(leftIndices); i++ {
        i1, _:= strconv.Atoi(leftIndices[i])
        i2, _:= strconv.Atoi(rightIndices[i])

        arr[i1], arr[i2] = arr[i2], arr[i1]
        fmt.Println(arr)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Even for this i need to handle so many cases (While still some remain not handled), making some thing generic will require even more checks and complexity

It will be way easier to use the builtin syntax like

```
a[0], a[1], a[2] = a[3], a[4], a[5]
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work. Let's say `a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` and the swap is `"1,3,5=>5,1,3"`. The result should be `[1, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4]`, while your solution gives `[1 4 3 2 5 6]`

Comment: Yes as you can see it is swapping sequentially it needs to be handled with copy(you will need to copy values before beginning to retain original values), I was just demonstrating a small example. A lot of still need to be handled as mentioned in answer